# NSMutable Array problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

All,

I have an issue with my NSMutable array LogoURL. when the UITable reloads it only shows at array location [0] and not at [1] or [2]. Here is my code, can someone look at see where I am going wrong. Its very minor problem but its driving me crazy!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MSTable *table;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *MainTableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // create the activity indicator in the main queue
    self.MainTableView.hidden = YES;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *ac = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:ac];
    [ac startAnimating];






    self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
    self.table = [self.client tableWithName:@"notifications"];
    self.logoURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MSQuery *query = [self.table query];
    query.fetchLimit = 3;
    [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error)
                                {

                                    self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];
                                    //[self.MainTableView reloadData];




                                    int a;
                                    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++)
                                    {
                                        NSDictionary *apt = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:a];
                                        NSLog(@"%@", apt[@"barID"]);
                                        NSDictionary *barIDDictionary = @{ @"myParam": apt[@"barID"]};
                                        self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
                                        [self.client invokeAPI:@"photos" body:barIDDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" parameters:nil headers:nil completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                                            if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Error %@", error );
                                            }
                                            else        {
                                                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"rows"]];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsend = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *stringWithoutbracketsfront = [stringWithoutbracketsend stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                                                NSString *completion = [stringWithoutbracketsfront stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                                                NSString *newStr = [completion substringFromIndex:1];
                                                NSString *finalstring = [newStr substringToIndex:newStr.length-(newStr.length>0)];
                                                [self.logoURL addObject:finalstring];
                                                [self.MainTableView reloadData];
                                            }




                                            }];

                                    }



                                }];

                                self.MainTableView.hidden = NO;


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.rowitems count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  NSDictionary *stress = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = stress[@"content"];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
          [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(0)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];

          break;

        case 1:
           [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(1)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];

            break;

        case 2:
            //[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.logoURL objectAtIndex:(2)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;

    }


    return cell;
}



@end
```

It is erroring at CASE (1), cos it cannot see the object. any help would be brilliant, thanks.

Comment: Did you debug how many items are in your array(s)?

Comment: I done a breakpoint yes, but it seems to not add them in - i don't think. any other tools I can use to debug this simple error ?

Comment: You should replace all the code in viewDidLoad method into init method, because it's have no connection with UI.

Comment: check your array count

Comment: the init method ? I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: initWithNibName:bundle or initWithCoder... some init method I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error at case (1) happens because you reload your table view 3 times. and every time you say to your tableView that it has 3 rows via `numberOfRowsInSection:` method. But in first and second iteration your self.logoURL has only 1 and then 2 objects. try this code:

```
if (self.logoURL.count > indexPath.row) {
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.logoURL[indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
    }
    else
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
```

also, you dont need to create NSMutableArray instance `self.rowitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` because you then reassign self.rowitems property `self.rowitems = [items mutableCopy];`

Comment: I think you may have cracked it! Let me change the urls and i may have a good result..

Comment: its still not perfect, cos it works sometimes and other times it errors. it needs a bit more work. I will repost the code when I have made sure the images come across, thanks.

Comment: in my opinion you should change `for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) NSDictionary *apt = [self.rowitems objectAtIndex:a];` to `for (NSDictionary *apt in self.rowitems)`, this will reduce one more error

Comment: one one run it works and another run , it doesn't work and complains about the array.. Not sure where to go with this one again.

Comment: check all `[<anyArray> objectAtIndex:index]` and make sure that index is less then <anyArray> objects count for that moment

Answer (score 0):

because your for loop is override the  array value and store last value only.

```
[array insertObject:finalString atIndex:i];

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.logoURL count];
}
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense .. what is the ALL ITEMS bit mean ? I mean what should I put in there ?

Comment: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array - same again

Comment: what is items in your block